# PostgreSQL vs MongoDB for performing python functions in Django app

Tags: database, mongodb, postgresql

I am trying to build a Django web app, and I'm not sure what database to use. It's really important to be able to perform python functions on the data and to have a high degree of data manipulation possibilities, with relatively fast-changing data(every day or every other day). Having made previous research it seems like PostgreSQL and MongoDB might be the contenders but I am really eager to hear your opinion. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What About Database Structure?**

**PostgreSQL:**

PostgreSQL is an object-relational database management system (ORDBMS) with an emphasis on extensibility and standards compliance. PostgreSQL is ACID-compliant, transactional, has updatable and materialized views, triggers, and foreign keys. It also supports functions and stored procedures.

PostgreSQL uses tables, constraints, triggers, roles, stored procedures and views as the core components that you work with. A table consists of rows, and each row contains a same set of columns. PostgreSQL uses primary keys to uniquely identify each row (a.k.a record) in a table, and foreign keys to assure the referential integrity between two related tables.

PostgreSQL also supports many NoSQL features as well.

**MongoDB:**

MongoDB uses JSON-like documents to store schema-free data. In MongoDB, collections of documents do not require a predefined structure and columns can vary for different documents.

MongoDB has many of the features of a relational database, including an expressive query language and strong consistency. However, since it is schema-free MongoDB allows you to create documents without having to create the structure for the document first.

A useful comparison with relational database management systems (RDBMS) in which you have:

`Table | Column | Value | Records.`

In comparison, in MongoDB you have:

`Collection | Key | Value | Document.`

This means that collections in MongoDB are like tables in RDBMS.

Documents are like records in a RDBMS. Documents can easily be modified by adding or deleting fields without having to restructure the entire document.

**Which Database Is Right For Your Business?**

**PostgreSQL:** PostgreSQL seems to be gaining more popularity. If you're looking for a solution that is standard compliant, transactional and ACID compliant out of the box and has wide support for NoSQL features, then you should check out PostgreSQL.

**MongoDB:** MongoDB can be a great choice if you need scalability and caching for real-time analytics; however, it is not built for transactional data (accounting systems, etc.). MongoDB is frequently used for mobile apps, content management, real-time analytics, and applications involving the Internet of Things. If you have no clear schema definition, MongoDB can be a good choice.